# Loop for creating csv out of dataframe column index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I want to create a loop which creates multiple csvs which have the same 9 columns in the beginning but differ iteratively in the last column.

```
[col1,col2,col3,col4,...,col9,col[i]]
```

I have a dataframe with a shape of (20000,209). 
What I want is that I create a loop which does not takes too much computation power and resources but creates 200 csvs which differ in the last column. All columns exist in one dataframe. The columns which should be added are in  columns i =[10:-1].

I thought of something like:

```
for col in df.columns[10:-1]:
dfi = df[:9] 
dfi.concat(df[10])
dfi.dropna()
dfi.to_csv('dfi.csv'))
```

Maybe it is also possible to use

```
dfi.to_csv('dfi.csv', sequence = [:9,i])
```

The i should display the number of the added column. Any idea how to make this happen easily? :)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand fully what you want but are you saying that each csv should just have 10 columns, all should have the first 9 and then one csv for each of the remaining 200 columns?

If so I would go for something as simple as:

```
base_cols = list(range(9))

for i in range(9, 209):
    df.iloc[:, base_cols+[i]].to_csv('csv{}.csv'.format(i))
```

Which should work I think.